# From C++ to MIPS - Structs

Tags: c++, struct, mips

Trying to understand how to take a struct from C++ (or any language) into MIPS. Lets say I have the following code snippet in C++:

```
struct pair {
    int x; 
    int y;
} myPair
```

How would I turn this piece of code into a piece of MIPS code. I am thinking I would need some form of `dw` statement. From here, how would I then create a function that accepts a pointer to the data, returning the sum of x and y in the AC register?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I can´t find (nor remember) a `dw` for MIPS. Anyways, You can treat them as two separate variables in memory, loading them separately into registers when one of them is needed etc.; with the exception that you know that y is right after x in memory and only a pointer to x is used.

Comment: In order to turn C++ code into MIPS machine code, I'd humbly suggest a compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @deviantfan. How would I get a compiler to output MIPS code...I am trying to build the above struct using MIPS

Comment: Compiler: A custom build of GCC can do that (or maybe you´ll find binaries somewhere), Manually: What do you not understand? And what is `dw`?